# laravel のblade の old 関数で値が表示されない理由は？

Tags: php, laravel

laravel10にて開発を行っています。
requestを処理して、その結果を表示しています。
その際の入力情報を表示させようとしているのですが、空欄のままになります。

ネットにあるコードを参考にしながら、コードを作成したのですが原因がわかりません。
どこに間違いがあるでしょうか？

resultの方は問題なく表示されています。

よろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/test" method="post">
    @csrf
    <label for="text">テキスト:</label>
    <textarea id="text" name="text" style="width:30rem;height:10rem">{{ old('text') }}</textarea>
    <button type="submit">送信</button>
</form>
<h2>結果</h2>
{!! $result !!}

</body>
</html>
```

controller側

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $text = $request->input('text');
    // 略
    $result = $this->generateHTMLTable($data);

    return view('yahoo_api_test', ['result' => $result, 'text' => $text]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return view() で text をそのまま返してるので，そちらを優先して使うと良いと思います．

具体的には，

```php
<textarea id="text" name="text" style="width:30rem;height:10rem">{{ $text }}</textarea>
```

とすると良さそうです．

追記:

old() ヘルパーは，実際には Request::old() を呼んでいます
参考: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/05c7572779746eb30229c52a329b9a079e54c9b1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L570-L573

実体の実装は以下です
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/05c7572779746eb30229c52a329b9a079e54c9b1/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithFlashData.php#L16-L21

```php
public function old($key = null, $default = null)
{
    $default = $default instanceof Model ? $default->getAttribute($key) : $default;

    return $this->hasSession() ? $this->session()->getOldInput($key, $default) : $default;
}
```

普通にやってればセッションは使ってると思いますが，今回の場合単に return view() してるだけですのでセッションに何も入ってません．
したがって view() に渡しているデータ（配列）を使うことになります．

ただし，リダイレクトさせる場合はこの限りではありません．
return redirect()->withInput() してあげることで，明示的にセッションに Form のデータが Flush されますので old() でも取れるようになると思います．

withInput() の中身は以下です
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/05c7572779746eb30229c52a329b9a079e54c9b1/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php#L74-L81

```php
public function withInput(array $input = null)
{
    $this->session->flashInput($this->removeFilesFromInput(
        ! is_null($input) ? $input : $this->request->input()
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

戻したい値だけ戻すこともできますし，何も指定しなければ Form からの入力が全部戻ります．

Comment: ありがとうございます！無事に表示されるようになりました。まだoldの挙動がわからないのですが、もう少し調べてみます。

Comment: old() について追記しました

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。仕組みを知ることはとても大切ですね。うまく動作しない理由が理解することができました。